# Access control after creating it at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created many textboxes at runtime then I want to add values to them.. after that I add a button to click on it and calculate all these values in the textboxes but I do n't know how can I access to these textboxes ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the method FindControl?

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs MyEventArgs)
{
  // Find control on page.
  Control myControl1 = FindControl("TextBox2");
  if(myControl1!=null)
  {
     // Get control's parent.
     Control myControl2 = myControl1.Parent;
     Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2.ID);
  }
  else
  {
     Response.Write("Control not found");
  }
```

}

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol(v=vs.71).aspx

I this method from time to time, as long as you know the name of the textbox or what ever control you need.

```
FindControl("textboxnamehere").Text = "This would put this string in the current text box";
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Joe W. But I've created the textboxes at runtime by for loop and I get each textbox the proprety ( MyControl.Name = "txb"+i;) so the name for each textbox is txb1 , txb2 ..etc so I can't write this  Control myControl1 = FindControl("TextBox2"); .. Can I ??

Comment: you should be able to use a loop counter for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
with that you could use x as your counter variable, because the loop is already keeping track of what x is. All you'd have to do is make an array type varriable similar to this:  Control myControl[x] = FindControl("textbox1[x]");

Answer (score 0):

this is just a sample, Lets assume you put your text boxes in a stackpanel - you need a container!,

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sum = 0.0;
        foreach (var child in stackPanel.Children)
        {
            var textBox = child as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) continue;
            double value;
            Double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value);
            sum += value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
```

of course, I am assuming you know that you might want to validate the input (use a numeric textblock), button.Click += Button_click; , etc..

**edit for a question**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i < grid.Children.Count; i++ )
        {
            var textBox = grid.Children[i] as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null) continue;
            double value;
            Double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value);
            sum += value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks denis morozov. This way works perfectly. I've tried it  with Grid instead stackPannel, but I have a problem..I do n't want to calculate the elements which allocate in the first row in the Grid. How can I do that ???

Comment: well, you could just skip first element, or start index at 1 (not zero)

Comment: I want to skip all the elements that allocate in the first row in Gris not only the first one. I have a Grid with two rows,each row contains 4 textboxes, I want to start calculating at the first element in the second row so I try to write: 
for (int i = (int)(length/2); i < grid3.Children.Count; i++)
length = total number of the textboxes in the table

Comment: so what is the problem, seems like at this point you have enough answers to know how to find the textBox, now you have another twist, right? So you have various options, one is that you could name your first textboxes something different and parse them out.

Comment: Thanks a lot denis , you 're amazing :)
I get the point , sorry for late :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have the TextBoxes in a container, like a StackPanel, you could do something like this...

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var total = 0;
    var textboxes = StackPanelParent.Children.OfType<TextBox>();

    foreach (var textbox in textboxes)
    {
         var input = 0;
         int.TryParse(textbox.Text, out input);
         total += input;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
}
```